# Trying to build nest functions within nested functions

Tags: javascript, function, nested

working on a script and I thought dot notation would be a good way of building methods to use later on in the grander scheme of the script.

the original system would declare functions written as

- memRead();
- memReadGlobal();
- memWrite();
- memEtc();.......

but I wanted to change this to

- mem.Read();
- mem.Read.Global();

Here is an example

```js
var mem = {
    Read: { 
        function() {
            console.log('Hello World')
        },
         Global: 
            function(key) {
                console.log('Goodbye World')
            },
    },
}
```

I can call `mem.Global` just fine, but I can't call `mem.Read`

I can declare mem.Read if I add another object like Local(`mem.Read.Local`), but I feel like writing local is redundant and would like to avoid that.

Is there a way to create a nested function like I describe above?

Comment: You are trying to do something that JavaScript object initializer syntax does not allow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that, but not with an object initializer expression.

```
var mem = {
    Read() {
        console.log("Hello from Read");
    }
};
mem.Read.Global = function() {
    console.log("Hello from Global");
};

mem.Read();
mem.Read.Global();
```

Comment: Also, and this is of course merely an opinion, function names should start with a lower-case letter unless they're intended to be used as constructors.

Comment: Thanks @Pointy this worked well and I'll note to keep these functions lowercase :) Self taught and still learning.
Thanks again :)